# isset _post for two dimensional array

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays

`<button type="submit" name="apply[<?php echo $temp['j_id']; ?>]"> Apply</button>`

`$temp['j_id'];` gets assigned randomly which is unique. I want to know which j_id button was clicked in the submitted page using $_POST and isset

Upon Clicking Apply, it takes to a different - here i want to check which values of apply[] was set using $_POST , i.e `if(isset($_POST['apply'][]))`

How to check isset for $_POST for two dimensional arrays

Comment: You might need to rewrite or add more details to your question because it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question a few times, I think I understand now. Check how I would tacked the problem in this code example in [**Runable**](http://runnable.com/VGlBSNxkqTYznjg8/output).

## Quick answer

> **How to check isset for $_POST for two dimensional arrays?**

```
if ( isset($_POST['apply']) && 
     isset($_POST['apply']['someuniqueid']) ) 
{
   //Do stuff
}
```

where `someuniqueid` is the id of the button.

---

## Longer answer

In your case, that `someuniqueid` is precisely what you want to figure. I'm assuming that this "ID" is meaningful and you know, beforehand, all the possible IDs. In that case, you need to test for each possible ID until a match is found. A simple way is storing those IDs in an array and then loop through it.

```
$possibleIDs = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

if ( isset($_POST['apply']) ) {
    foreach ($possibleIDs as $id) {
        if ( isset($_POST['apply'][$id]) ) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Suggestion

However, this is quite inefficient because you need to create an array with IDs and then loop through it to find a value. In fact, it does not make much sense to use an array "key" as a "value". Also, "key" names might be converted/changed (for instance, `array('8' => 'foo')` will be converted to `array(8 => 'foo')`.

A better approach, IMHO, would be to assign that id to the buttons value.

```
<button type="submit" name="apply" value="<?php echo $temp['j_id']; ?>"> Apply</button>
```

In the receiving script, your button id is `$_POST['apply']` value.

You can check this example in [**Runable**](http://runnable.com/VGlBSNxkqTYznjg8/output). Notice that only the button clicked is assigned a value. The other buttons are not submitted.